# Push Values Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm having issues in pushing and returning an array with the events titles. As far as i'm concerned, this should append the title of the events into the titulos array.

```
 for (j=0;j<events.length;j++){ 
  var titulos = []
  var events =a.getEventsForDay(testingstartdate, {search: 'OOO'});
  var eventstitle = events[j].getTitle(); 
  Logger.log(eventstitle);
  titulos.push(eventstitle);
  };
```

The Logger.log in question here is returning correctly one row per title, so no sure why the final array is only pushing 1 single value to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Logger.log in question here is returning correctly one row per
>   title, so no sure why the final array is only pushing 1 single value
>   to it.

This is happening because you define your array in each step of the for loop. Moving the following statement:

```
var titulos = [];
```

before the start of the `for` loop will solve your problem.

Comment: Oh yeah! Thanks so much. Worked as a charm!